# Swift IAP multiple Transaction when go back and turn again view controller

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

Hello I have working app , and when user click buy limits view controller (first click ) user bought everything good but when user go back to main controller and go again buy limits view controller and user click buy IAP doing double transactions and user also go again main controller and go again buy limits view controller when click buy IAP doing triple transactions ..  how can i resolve this problem my codes under below.

PaymentManager

```
import UIKit
import StoreKit

protocol PurchaseManagerDelegate
{
    func refreshList()
    func restoreCompleted()
    func transactionIsActive()
}

class PurchaseManager: NSObject
{
    var productsArray = [SKProduct]()
    var purchaseItemID = ""

    var getprice:NSDecimalNumber = 0.00

    var delegate: PurchaseManagerDelegate?

    var transactionProgress = false

    var productsLoadedNotification = "productsLoadedNotification"

    var appusername:String? = prefs.valueForKey("email") as! String!


    // MARK: - Load product methods

    func loadPaymentInfo()
    {
        requestProductInfo()
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
    }

    func requestProductInfo()
    {
        let productIDs = getProductIDs()

        if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()
        {
            let productRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIDs)
            productRequest.delegate = self

            productRequest.start()
        }
        else
        {
            print("Cannot perform In App Purchases.")
        }
    }

    func getProductIDs() -> Set<String>
    {
        var result = Set<String>()

        if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("PurchaseID", ofType: "plist")
        {
            if let items = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path)
            {
                for purchaseGroups in items
                {
                    if let array = purchaseGroups as? [String]
                    {
                        for purchaseID in array
                        {
                            result.insert(purchaseID)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return result
    }

    // MARK: - Purchase methods

    func buyProduct(productID: String)
    {
        if transactionProgress
        {
            self.delegate?.transactionIsActive()
            return
        }

        for product in productsArray
        {

            let payment:SKMutablePayment = SKMutablePayment(product: product)

            if (productID == product.productIdentifier)
            {
                purchaseItemID = product.productIdentifier

                getprice = product.price

                payment.applicationUsername = self.appusername!;

                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(payment)
                self.transactionProgress = true
            }
        }
    }

    func restorePurchases()
    {
        if transactionProgress
        {
            self.delegate?.transactionIsActive()
            return
        }
        transactionProgress = true
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()
    }

    // MARK: - Functional methods

    func getProductTitle(productID: String) -> String?
    {
        for product in productsArray
        {
            if (productID == product.productIdentifier)
            {
                return product.localizedTitle
            }
        }

        return nil
    }



    func getProductPrice(productID: String) -> String?
    {
        for product in productsArray
        {
            if (productID == product.productIdentifier)
            {
                let numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
                numberFormatter.formatterBehavior = .Behavior10_4
                numberFormatter.numberStyle = .CurrencyStyle
                numberFormatter.locale = product.priceLocale

                return numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(product.price)!
            }
        }

        return nil
    }

    func productsAreLoaded() -> Bool
    {
        if (productsArray.count > 0)
        {
            return true
        }
        else
        {
            return false
        }
    }


    func isProductBought(productID: String) -> Bool
    {

        if(productID == "com.blaSupport" || productID == "com.bla.Show"){

            return false

        }else{

            return false
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - Product request methods

extension PurchaseManager: SKProductsRequestDelegate
{
    func productsRequest(request: SKProductsRequest, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse)
    {
        if response.products.count != 0
        {
            productsArray = response.products
        }

        if response.invalidProductIdentifiers.count != 0
        {
            print(response.invalidProductIdentifiers.description)
        }

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(productsLoadedNotification, object: nil)
    }

}

// MARK: - Transaction delegate methods

extension PurchaseManager: SKPaymentTransactionObserver
{
    func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction])
    {
        for transaction in transactions
        {
            switch transaction.transactionState
            {
            case .Purchasing:
                print("Transaction in Progress")
            case .Purchased:
                print("Transaction completed successfully.")
                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction)

                // SUCCESS GIVE LIMITS

                self.transactionProgress = false
                // Give limits
                BuyLimitsViewController.sharedInstance.giveLimits(self.purchaseItemID)
                self.setPurchasedProduct(self.purchaseItemID)

                self.delegate?.refreshList()


                // Send Values 
                let addIAPUrl = "http://bla.com/)&price=\(getprice)"
                self.sendIAP(addIAPUrl, completionHandler: { (success, message) -> Void in


                        if(success == 1){

                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){

                                // ADDED

                            }

                        }else{

                            // DONT ADDED
                        }

                    })

            case .Failed:
                print("Transaction Failed");
                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction)
                transactionProgress = false
                self.delegate?.refreshList()
            case .Restored:
                print("Restore completed successfully.")
                let identifier = transaction.originalTransaction!.payment.productIdentifier
                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction)
                transactionProgress = false
                self.setPurchasedProduct(identifier)
            case .Deferred:
                print("Transaction defered.")
                print(transaction.transactionState.rawValue)
                transactionProgress = false
                self.delegate?.refreshList()
            }
        }
    }



    func sendIAP(url : String, completionHandler : ((success : Int, message : String) -> Void)) {

        guard let url = NSURL(string: url as String) else {
            completionHandler(success: 0, message: "Couldn't get URL")
            return
        }

        let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
        let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
        let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)

        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest, completionHandler: { (data,  response, error) in
            guard let responseData = data else {
                completionHandler(success: 0, message: "Data was nil")
                return
            }
            guard error == nil else {
                print(error)
                completionHandler(success: 0, message: "Error wasn't nil")
                return
            }

            let post: NSDictionary
            do {
                post = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData,
                    options: []) as! NSDictionary
            } catch  {
                completionHandler(success: 0, message: "Error with NSJSONSerialization")
                return
            }

            let numberFromString = Int((post["success"] as? String)!)


            completionHandler(success: (numberFromString)!, message: (post["message"] as? String)!)



        })
        task.resume()


    }


    func setPurchasedProduct(productID: NSString)
    {
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: productID as String)
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    }

    func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(queue: SKPaymentQueue) {
        print("Restore Completed")
        self.delegate?.restoreCompleted()
    }


}
```

And here my buyView controller

```
import UIKit
import StoreKit

class BuyLimitsViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, PurchaseManagerDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

    static let sharedInstance = BuyLimitsViewController()

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var items = []

    var purchaseManager = PurchaseManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        purchaseManager.delegate = self
        purchaseManager.loadPaymentInfo()

        if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("PurchaseID", ofType: "plist")
        {
            if let fileItems = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path)
            {
                items = fileItems
            }
        }

        let mainQueue = NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(purchaseManager.productsLoadedNotification, object: nil, queue: mainQueue) { _ in
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

    }

    // MARK: - TableView delegate

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int
    {
        return items.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        var numberOfItems = 0
        if let purchaseItems = items[section] as? [String]
        {
            numberOfItems = purchaseItems.count
        }

        return numberOfItems
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("StoreTableViewCell") as! StoreTableViewCell

        if let purchaseItems = items[indexPath.section] as? [String]
        {
            let productID = purchaseItems[indexPath.row]
            if purchaseManager.productsAreLoaded()
            {
                cell.accessoryView = nil
                cell.titleLabel.text = purchaseManager.getProductTitle(productID)
                cell.priceLabel.text = purchaseManager.getProductPrice(purchaseItems[indexPath.row])

            }
            else
            {
                cell.titleLabel.text = ""
                cell.priceLabel.text = ""
                if (indexPath.section == 0) && (indexPath.row == 0)
                {
                    cell.titleLabel.text = "Loading..."
                    cell.accessoryView = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray)
                    (cell.accessoryView as! UIActivityIndicatorView).startAnimating()
                }
            }
        }

        return cell
    }


    func giveLimits(purhased : NSString) {


        let postEndpointLost:NSString = "http://bla.com/"
        user.sharedInstance.apiRequest(postEndpointLost as String, completionHandler: { (success, message) -> Void in

            if(success == 1){

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){


                }

            }else{

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){


                }

            }

        })

    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {
        if let purchaseItems = items[indexPath.section] as? [String]
        {
            let productID = purchaseItems[indexPath.row]
            if !purchaseManager.isProductBought(productID)
            {
                purchaseManager.buyProduct(purchaseItems[indexPath.row])
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func restoreButtonSelector(sender: AnyObject) {
        purchaseManager.restorePurchases()
    }

    // MARK: - Purchase Manager delegate

    func refreshList()
    {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func transactionIsActive()
    {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "Transaction is already in progress. Please wait to finish.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { alertAction in
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            alert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }))

        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func restoreCompleted()
    {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "Restore completed.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { alertAction in
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            alert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }))

        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }



}
```

Output example for each load buyviewcontroller +1 count this output example

```
Transaction in Progress
Transaction in Progress
Transaction in Progress
Transaction in Progress
```

I think maybe needs clear somethings when userclick buy limits view controller i need your helps Thank you !

Comment: any idea ? how can i resolve it ? i think somethings wrong in buy limits view controller override func viewDidLoad() { } inside ? when user turn again buy limits view controller repeat somethings ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not do `removeTransactionObserver`. So every time in `viewDidLoad()` it is adding transaction observer on the default paymentQueue

```
SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
```

To counter that, do `removeTransactionObserver` in `viewWillDisappear`. In `StoreViewController` write:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    purchaseManager.removeTransactionObserver()
}
```

Add a function in `PurchaseManager`:

```
func removeTransactionObserver()
{
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().removeTransactionObserver(self)
}
```